# Add a link to the Activity > Reputation > Next tag badge section of the user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

If you go to your user profile you can see what badge you're closest to earning.

[image: Next tag badge]

When I click on the badge displayed, it tells me the criteria to earn the badge, and my own progress is already displayed on the right. This is helpful information, but can you also add a link to the newest questions in that tag? Maybe in the pop-up message the tag name could be a link? For example:

> Bronze [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag badge

Since I'm so close to earning a badge, the natural thing for me to want to do is go answer a few questions. Clicking a link to the newest questions in that tag would be a little bit more convenient than going to tag search and typing in the tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was completed with the recent addition of the "Go get it" button to the UI.

[image: Go get it]